# size() is printing multiple times

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out why the arr.size() is printing multiple times (the same number as the size).

I'm supposed to take an array and state, to an accuracy of 6 decimal places, what portion of the array is positive, negative, or zero. But, I can't seem to get past the multiple lines printing.

```
class Result {

    public static void plusMinus(List<Integer> arr) {
        int plus = 0;
        int minus = 0;
        int zero = 0;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
            if (i == 0) {
                zero++;
            } else if (i < 0) {
                minus++;
            } else if (i > 0) {
                plus++;
            }
        
        double plusPortion = plus / arr.size();
        double minusPortion = minus / arr.size();
        double zeroPortion = zero / arr.size();
        
        System.out.println(arr.size());
        //System.out.println(plusPortion);
        //System.out.println(minusPortion);
        //System.out.println(zeroPortion);
        }
        
        
    }

}

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int n = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());

        List<Integer> arr = Stream.of(bufferedReader.readLine().replaceAll("\\s+$", "").split(" "))
            .map(Integer::parseInt)
            .collect(toList());

        Result.plusMinus(arr);

        bufferedReader.close();
    }
}
```

The Solution class was provided as part of the challenge.

Comment: you have a problem in your forloop, you using the value of `i`, but instead you should use the value of `arr.get(i)`

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you exactly want to do?
You're obviously printing out the size under the for loop.

Comment: Your `System.out.println` statement is inside the loop. Java uses braces `{` ... `}`, not indentation, to denote blocks of code.

Comment: You have messed up your indentation, and now you are printing the size *within* the for loop.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize I was still in the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move size printing and portion calculation outside the loop, like this:

```
public static void plusMinus(List<Integer> arr) {
    int plus = 0;
    int minus = 0;
    int zero = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.size(); ++i) {
        if (i == 0) {
            zero++;
        } else if (i < 0) {
            minus++;
        } else if (i > 0) {
            plus++;
        }
    }
    //calculate portions
    double plusPortion = plus / arr.size();
    double minusPortion = minus / arr.size();
    double zeroPortion = zero / arr.size();
    //log results
    System.out.println("Array size:" + arr.size());
    //System.out.println(plusPortion);
    //System.out.println(minusPortion);
    //System.out.println(zeroPortion);   
}
```

You need to make 'calculations' in the for loop, then print the results. In the code you posted, you were printing results for each step/element of the list.